# Why we can't use UseDispatch in stateful component?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Why we can not use Hook UseDispatch in stateful component?

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { submitData } from "../state/actions";

class FormComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
     this.state = {
       fields: {},
       errors: {}
     };
  }

 submitForm = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.validateForm()) {
      useDispatch(submitData(this.state.fields));
    }
  };
}

}
```

I created stateful component for the simple form with fields and also tracked all the data in state.fields, I want to use Hook method UseDispatch.
Why I can not use Hook in this?

Comment: `hooks` don't work for class based components

Comment: [Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) are the new thing which brings state to function components. Class components already have a state and lifecycle methods.

Comment: Rules of React Hooks: Only Call Hooks from React Functions, see: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html.

Comment: Even if this were a functional component and you could use hooks, this isn't even how useDispatch works. See https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#usedispatch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using a stateful component (class inheriting from React.Component or PureComponent), you cannot use the UseDispatch hook, or any hooks.

As Dupocas said, hooks are only availables in [function components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).

Instead you need to connect the component to the redux store with the [`connect`](https://react-redux.js.org/7.0/api/connect#connect) utility from `react-redux`:

```
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';

    import { submitData } from "../state/actions";

    class FormComponent extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                fields: {},
                errors: {}
            };
        }

        submitForm = e => {
            const { dispatchSubmitData } = this.props;
            e.preventDefault();
            if (this.validateForm()) {
                dispatchSubmitData(this.state.fields);
            }
        };
    }


    const mapStateToProps = null;
    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
        return {
            dispatchSubmitData: (...args) => dispatch(submitData(...args))
        };
    }

    export connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FormComponent);
```

[documentation for mapStateToProps](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch)